# How to check whether string might be type-cast to float in Python?

Tags: python, floating-point

Is there some function like `str.isnumeric` but applicable to float?

```
'13.37'.isnumeric() #False
```

I still use this:

```
def isFloat(string):
    try:
        float(string)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

Comment: A more consistent and complete answer:

`
def strType(xstr):
 try:
  int(xstr)
  return 'int'
 except:
  try:
   float(xstr)
   return 'float'
  except:
   try:
    complex(xstr)
    return 'complex'
   except:
    return 'str'


print("4", strType("4"))
print("12345678901234567890", strType("12345678901234567890"))
print("4.1", strType("4.1"))
print("4.1+3j", strType("4.1+3j"))
print("a", strType("a"))
`

Comment: '13.37'.replace(".","").isnumeric():

Comment: I like @GrigoryIlizirov answer the best because it doesn't invoke an exception.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As Imran says, your code is absolutely fine as shown.

However, it does encourage clients of `isFloat` down the "Look Before You Leap" path instead of the more Pythonic "Easier to Ask Forgiveness than Permission" path.

It's more Pythonic for clients to assume they have a string representing a float but be ready to handle the exception that will be thrown if it isn't.

This approach also has the nice side-effect of converting the string to a float once instead of twice.

Comment: +1: @pingvinus: Please don't waste time writing such things.  Just write your real application.  If it throws a `ValueError` that means the input wasn't valid float and an overall exception handler can report this.  There's no need to pre-check for float values, since the `float` function does this right when you need it.  And always correctly.

Comment: Although i see the point in try catch, I think that doing it a lot "could" be expensive to handle the exception. I am surprised that the isfloat helper is not available,

Comment: @S.Lott That's not necessarily true. There are very good applications for a function like this when you need to make a decision based on an unknown value. This is far more readable.

Answer (score 4):

A more complete generalization:

```
    def strType(xstr):
        try:
            int(xstr)
            return 'int'
        except:
            try:
                float(xstr)
                return 'float'
            except:
                try:
                    complex(xstr)
                    return 'complex'
                except:
                    return 'str'


    print("4", strType("4"))
    print("12345678901234567890", strType("12345678901234567890"))
    print("4.1", strType("4.1"))
    print("4.1+3j", strType("4.1+3j"))
    print("a", strType("a"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is absolutely fine. Regex based solutions are more likely to be error prone.

Quick testing with `timeit` reveals `float(str_val)` is indeed faster than `re.match()`

```
>>> timeit.timeit('float("-1.1")')
1.2833082290601467
>>> timeit.timeit(r"pat.match('-1.1')", "import re; pat=re.compile(r'^-?\d*\.?\d+(?:[Ee]-?\d+)?$');")
1.5084138986904527
```

And the regex used above fails one edge case, it can't match `'-1.'`, although `float()` will happily convert it to proper float value.

Comment: I think I remember seeing a thread about this on a mailing list a long time ago.  The gist was that float() and a regex were about the same speed.

Comment: It's not a Python-way I think - 6 lines of code to solve common problem. But, thanks.

Comment: Using re.compile will make the regexp pretty much the same speed as float().

Comment: @Imran: your performance comparison is not correct, while `float` would be faster, you need to compile regex outside of the execution loop, it needs to be re-used for that method to be practical.

Comment: Performance with compiled regex is even worse :P. How could that be? The `setup` statement in `timeit.timeit` is eval'ed just once, isn't it?

Comment: gosh, you need to do `pat.match('1.1')`. Also `match` is always starting from the start of the subject string, no `^` required.

Comment: @SilentGhost: Thanks, now regex's performance is lot closer to `float` :)

Comment: The regexp needs to also match floats written with an exponent, for example '10e-2'

Comment: @Paul: Updated the regex to match exponent

Comment: What about when isFloat() fails? How long does throwing and catching an exception/error take?

Answer (score 1):

There's a catch though:
float('nan') returns nan, no exception raised ;)

Comment: `nan` and `inf` (positive and negative) are floats, as `1.e9`. [GNU libc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Infinity-and-NaN.html), [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point)... so that's valid

Answer (score 0):

Extending from @Imran's results:

```
>>> timeit('float("-1.1")', number=10000000)
1.365271806716919

>>> timeit(r"isfloat('-1.1')", """def isfloat(s): t = s.partition('.');
           return t[1] and t[0].isdigit() and (not t[2] or t[2].isdigit());""",
           number=10000000)
2.565232992172241

>>> timeit(r"pat.match('-1.1')", "import re; pat=re.compile(r'^-?\d*\.?\d+(
    ...: ?:[Ee]-?\d+)?$');", number=10000000)
3.258622169494629
```

My `partition` solution is much faster than regex, but slower than `float`; however has the advantage of not raising errors (so you can use it in e.g.: comprehensions).

This handles edge conditions like `1.`, but not specialisations like `NaN`.

Answer (score -2):

`isinstance(myVariable, float)` will work if you're testing a floating point variable.

Edit: Spoke too soon, didn't fully understand what you were trying to get.

Comment: that's not what OP wants